# How to style Angular4 custom components based on attribute?

Tags: angular, typescript, polymer

In Polymer we have this concept where we add specific properties to certain components, and then style that component with associated attribute. (This way, it differentiates them from the same component that doesnt have that attribute.

For example

### Polymer

```html
<osb-retailer-details overlay></osb-retailer-details>
<osb-retailer-details></osb-retailer-details>
```

And then to style `<osb-retailer-details>` component with `overlay` attribute, we do the following:

```css
:host {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  
  &[overlay] {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

### Now my question

In angular4, can we do the same thing? Where we pass attribute to component, and style it, just like above?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it basically works the same way: http://plnkr.co/edit/OZv3AL1YsHYQHedXTjBr?p=preview

Comment: I see. So judging by that, this means that If I'm passing an object to a child component (e.g <osb-retailer-details [prevCard] ="person"></ osb-retailer-details>). I can style the child component by doing `:host[prevCard]{...}`? @JBNizet

Comment: Well, yes. Why don't you test it?

Comment: @JBNizet It didnt work :( not sure why, but it made sense so much. It should've worked

Comment: actually, it worked. Lmao, not sure why. Just refreshed the page @JBNizet

Comment: Please right your answer below, so that I can accept your help :) @JBNizet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it basically works the same way. Here's [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/OZv3AL1YsHYQHedXTjBr?p=preview).

component definition:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'osb-retailer-details',
  template: '<div>hello world</div>',
  styleUrls: ['src/retailer-details.css']
})
export class RetailerDetails {

}
```

src/retailer-details.css file:

```
:host {
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
}

:host[overlay] {
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you bud. Really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<osb-retailer-details [attr.overlay]="'overlay'"></osb-retailer-details>
```

and then the rest is the same