# how to style angular 4 component with an attribute?

Tags: angular, typescript, attributes

I have a component that in which I'd like to pass certain data to the child component in `ngFor` through attribute. And based on attribute I'd like to ultimately style those child-components.

## Code

**`testimonials.component.html - (Parent component)`**

```html
<ng-template ngFor let-person="$implicit" [ngForOf]="peopleAsPreviousCurrentAndNextTriplets" let-i=index let-last=last>
    <app-card
           [prevCard]      ="last ? person.previous : null"
           [currentCard]   ="last ? person.current : null"
           [nextCard]      ="last ? person.next : null"
    ></app-card>
</ng-template>
```

**`card.component.ts - (Child component)`**

```js
import {Component, Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Person} from '../testimonials/person';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.scss']
})
export class CardComponent {
  @Input() decrement:     Number;
  @Input() defaultDiff:   Number;
  @Input() currentCard:   Person;
  @Input() prevCard:      Person;
  @Input() nextCard:      Person;
  @ViewChild('card')      card;

  constructor() { }
}
```

And I would like to style `<app-card>` with a `[currentCard]` attribute.

**`child.component.sass`**

```css
:host {
  &[currentCard] {
    .testimonials__card-container {
      background-color: black;
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure why the above style is not being applied.

Please help.

Thanks

## EDIT

Here's to visualise my tacked cards:

[image]

Comment: `[currentCard]` is a *binding*, it doesn't actually apply that attribute. Try putting a class on the element conditionally instead.

Comment: Your question was my daily dose of SO. Thank you for this.

Comment: Lol, Im not sure if should be happy about that. Apologies if I caused you any annoyance @Moshe

Comment: I learned something new* :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mix up html attributes and Angular bindings. What would work is something like this:

in the parent view:

```
   <app-card [class.currentcard]= "last"
               [prevCard]      ="last ? person.previous : null"
               [currentCard]   ="last ? person.current : null"
               [nextCard]      ="last ? person.next : null">
    </app-card>
```

and in the stylesheet of the child:

```
:host(.currentcard) {
   background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: OMG, I really apologise for not getting back to you soon. And yes this was very helpful, and I really appreciate it. Just one question though. I come from Polymerjs background and the way we do it is style it based on attribute you pass. And then target it within the host. Heres a similar question I asked earlier. But it didnt work at the end. I misundertood it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45691491/how-to-style-angular4-custom-components-based-on-attribute/45692412#45692412

Comment: Would it be possible to do it angular4 though? I'd prefer not to add class at all in the first place. And just style it within host

Comment: Well not exactly, so think of this as a gallery (stacked items galler) - where the current one will be at the top of the stack, and the [prevCard] will be behind the current card but on the left, and the [rightCard] will on behind the currentCard but on the right. And there will be two buttons, when I click next, the current card becomes the prevCard, and the nextCard becomes the currentCard. Do u get the idea?

Comment: So basiclaly, I thought it would be trivial having a class for each one. Why not just deal with them durectly in the host. without classes

Comment: Well, JBNizet's answer doesn't actually work. I tried doing what he suggested. But didn't work.

Comment: Cheers Vega, appreciate ur help XD

Comment: Check my image in edited section to help you in any way.

Comment: Hi there, any luck m8?

Comment: apologies for nagging you

Comment: No problem, it's fun :) I made a plunker that approxiamtely does the card effect. There is no need for angular even, I just put a button for the form and to add some angular. Otherwise just add "active" in the class list to have permanent effect. teel me what you think : https://plnkr.co/edit/Ozp6BF8SwOP9XzeHpz5K?p=preview

Comment: I see what you did there. Very thorough approach. However, my stacked cards will not always be around 3 items. Its dynamic. For example, lets say I'm making an API request which returns a collection. Then for each item in the collection. There will be a card. Also. The reason why I need angular binding is because I'll need to be passing the collection item to the stacked card component. But also styling it with an attribute.

Comment: Sorry for making this so long and annoying. Hope you understand the issue here

Comment: No worries! You cannot display an infinite number of cards any way. You can restrain the number to 3 (or a reasonable number) and make the css accordingly. The other have to wait behind the last one, which is not impossible with css only. what do you think?

Comment: hmm I see your point. Your right. Thanks for your help. Will accept your answer :)